# Notification if user modifies contents of documents directory via iTunes File sharing

Tags: iphone, ios

I am looking for a reliable way to get a notification if the user has modified the contents of the document directory via itunes file sharing while the app is running.

I rather not use

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

because this is not reliable with iOS 5 because you can change the documents directory without this method being called..

I have also looked into Apple's DirectoryWatcher class and found that it does not work on iOS 4.3 and later.

Edit:
As per the answer below this DirectoryWatcher does infact work, i had just missed that it is by default autoreleased.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple's DirectoryWatcher looks good. I haven't fully tested it but from a cursory look...

You have to upgrade it to iOS5 - but XCode prompts you to do this. This results in a project with one error which can be resolved by adding the QLPreviewControllerDelegate to DITableViewController interface.

```
@interface DITableViewController : UITableViewController <QLPreviewControllerDataSource,
                                                      DirectoryWatcherDelegate,QLPreviewControllerDelegate,
                                                      UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate>
```

Comment: I have updated my post, you were correct that it does work for iphone, but for some reason it is not firing on the ipad

Comment: It works on iPad device for me if I set the targeted device to ipad and run.

Comment: Uggh, i did not see the autorelease at first, thus the callbacks were happening after the releasepool got to it.  Thanks.    DirectoryWatcher *tempManager = [[[DirectoryWatcher alloc] init] autorelease];