# How detect changes in the application documents directory in iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, nsfilemanager

I am currently working on an app with the file sharing feature.
We have a view to ask the user to plug his device to iTunes to add files if there is no files in the app.

I would like to remove this view when the iOS app is launched on the device and when the user add at least one file with iTunes to the app.

Is there a way to do that with the default FileManager ? Like a delegate or something to detect events from the document directory of the app ?

I have looked on the web and found some pods but only for macOS.

I have also tried something with a Timer which will get the files from the document directory of the app each 0.25 seconds, but I don't think this is the best way to do what I want.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT:
Thanks to the MartinR's comment below, the following link helps me to do what I wanted
[Notification if user modifies contents of documents directory via iTunes File sharing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7741948/notification-if-user-modifies-contents-of-documents-directory-via-itunes-file-sh)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7741948/notification-if-user-modifies-contents-of-documents-directory-via-itunes-file-sh

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look

Comment: @MartinR thanks for your answer, it works perfectly!